# Change switch value without change all of them

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm a beginner and I don't know how to change switch value without change all of them. You can see the code about. I'm mapping a nested array on return. I'm confuse how to change the switch status individually. I've tried some solutions like change the value inside the array with an onchange event but it doenst reender the screen.

```
const [dtData, setDtData] = useState('release_data');
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      getManagerListDay(function(resultado) {
        setDtData(resultado);
      });
      setInterval(() => {
        getManagerListDay(function(resultado) {
          setDtData(resultado);
        });
        toasted.showToast('Refresh');
      }, 60000);

    }, [])
  );

const section  = [];
for ( var i = 0, ii = dtData.length; i < ii; i++ ) {

  if(i>0?dtData[i].dayDate != dtData[i-1].dayDate:true == true){
    const items = [];
    for ( var b = 0, bb = dtData.length; b < bb; b++ ) {

      if(dtData[b].dayDate == dtData[i].dayDate){
          items.push({
            name: dtData[b].name,
            worked: dtData[b].worked,
            workedWeekDays: dtData[b].workedWeekDays,
            KeyItemDriver: dtData[b].KeyItemDriver
          });
      }
    }

    section.push({
      dayDate: dtData[i].dayDate,
      driverAmount: dtData[i].driverAmountAccepted,
      keySectionDay: dtData[i].keySectionDay,
      data: items
    });
  }
}

  return (
    <Root>
    <View style={{marginTop:15}}>
      {section.map((obj, index) => {
        return(
          <List.Section  
            title={obj.dayDate} 
            titleStyle={{color:'black',fontWeight:'bold', fontSize: 16}} 
            style={{backgroundColor:'rgba(79,79,79,0.1)', marginTop:0, borderRadius:30, width:'90%',alignSelf:'center'}}
            key={index}
            id={obj.keySectionDay}  >

            <Button mode="contained" style={{borderRadius:70,width:40,backgroundColor:'#48D1CC', marginLeft:'80%'}}> 
            <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold', marginRight:50}}> {obj.driverAmount} </Text> </Button>
            <FAB style={styles.fab} color='white' small={false} icon="database-export" onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')} />
                
            <List.Accordion
              title="DRIVERS"
              key={index}
              theme={{ colors: { primary: '#48D1CC' }}}
              titleStyle={{color:'black', fontSize:14}}
              left={props => <List.Icon {...props} icon="folder"/>}>

              {obj.data.map((dts,index) => {
                return(
                  <List.Item key={index} id={dts.KeyItemDriver} title={dts.name} titleStyle={{color:'black'}} 
                    style={{borderTopColor:'white', borderTopWidth:1}} 
                    left={props => <Switch {...props} color={dts.worked=='S'?'#48D1CC':'red'} value={dts.worked!=null?true:false}/>}
                    right={props => <Text {...props} style={{color:'#48D1CC',fontSize:18, marginTop:5}} > {dts.workedWeekDays} </Text>}
                    onPress={() => alert('Sou eu')} 
                  />
                )
              })}
            </List.Accordion>
          </List.Section>
          );
        })
      }
    </View>
    </Root>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind! I was thinking wrong about the steps process. I need.
I just update the information on the database and rerender the screen from there. What I think is correct. I must show what is commited.
Thanks!